Check if viewer node is on or off
Is it possible to check with python if a viewer node is on or off?
So this:

vs:

I tried hide, active and bl_iconand I think it's not exposed to the user.
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GeometryNodeViewer.html
